# $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{2^{k}}}$ is rational?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

The question is:  $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{2^{k}}}$ is rational?

**Remark:** By root test we know that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{2^{k}}}$ converge.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number

Comment: Or simply by the fact that $\frac{1}{k^{2^k}}\leq \frac{1}{k^2}$. :)

Comment: I'm not so sure this number is a **Liouville number**. On the other hand, i don't see because the fact $\frac{1}{k^{2^{k}}} \leq \frac{1}{k^{2}}$ implies that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{2^{k}}}$ is rational or irrational.

Comment: @diegofonseca06 I think Thomas meant that _convergence_ follows from comparison to this series (i.e. root test isn't necessary here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from theorem A of [this paper](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa63/aa6342.pdf). Namely, take $b_n=1,a_n=n^{2^n}$. Then we surely have $a_{n+1}=(n+1)^{2^{n+1}}>n^{2^{n+1}}=(n^{2^n})^2=a_n^2\geq a_n^2-a_n+1=\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}a_n^2-\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}a_n+1$, so sum of the series $\sum\frac{b_n}{a_n}=\sum\frac{1}{n^{2^n}}$ is irratonal.